# How can I insert constant sender e-mail adress in vb automatic e-mail?

Tags: vb.net

This sends an automatic email the by user who uses the program, but I want an email to be sent from the same email address no matter who uses it.

Here my code. Could you help me please ?

```vb
Dim msgBody
Dim thresholdInfo
Dim receipAddress

'msgBody=""+vbNewLine
thresholdInfo="xxx :"+CStr(Threshold.StatValue)+vbNewLine+vbNewLine
receipAddress="xx"
cc="xx"

SendMail receipAddress,msgBody+thresholdInfo,"xxxxxx"

Sub SendMail(recipient,msg,subject)
    
    Dim objOutlook 
    Dim objOutlookMsg 
    
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject( "Outlook.Application" )
    Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    objOutlookMsg.To = recipient
    objOutlookMsg.Cc = cc
    objOutlookMsg.Subject = subject
    
    objOutlookMsg.Body = msg
    
    objOutlookMsg.Importance = Low
    
    objOutlookMsg.Send
    
    Set objOutlookMsg = Nothing
    
    Set objOutlook = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried declaring the Sender first:

```
Dim Sender As Outlook.AddressEntry
Sender.Address = "your@email.com"
```

Then finally including it in your `Sub SendMail(recipient,msg,subject)`:

```
objOutlookMsg.Sender = Sender
```

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sender

Comment: I tried like this but it didn't work.
`Dim SenderAddress 

SenderAddress="requestedaddress@mail.com"
SendMail SenderAddress,receipAddress,msgBody+thresholdInfo,"xxx."
Sub SendMail(sender,recipient,msg,subject)

Dim objOutlook 
Dim objOutlookMsg 

Set objOutlook = CreateObject( "Outlook.Application" )
Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

objOutlookMsg.Sender = SenderAddress


objOutlookMsg.Body = msg

objOutlookMsg.Importance = Low

objOutlookMsg.Send

Set objOutlookMsg = Nothing

Set objOutlook = Nothing

End Sub`

Comment: According to the Microsoft's documentation ```Sender``` should be ```Outlook.AddressEntry```- this is not the case in the example you shared.

Comment: When I tried like you said it gives an error. Error message is ''Expected end of statement."  I can't understand where I went wrong. Could you send me full code please Ivan ?

Comment: I've not sent emails using this method in VB (I use Graph and C#). You can also try ```objOutlookMsg.SentOnBehalfOfName = "your@email.com"```